# trim and string_split don't work in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split, sql-server-2012

I'm asking because I need to know why some functions (split_string, trim) don't work in SQL Server (using SSMS).

If I run something like this:

```
SELECT TRIM('   SQL Tutorial! ') AS TrimmedString;
```

It says

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 60
>   'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name.

So yeah, I can use `rtrim` or `ltrim`, but I also need `string_split` for another task.

So then the question is what version do I have? In Help/About, it says v17.9.1. But according to this page, it pretty clearly says it is supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

So why the heck doesn't it work?

Comment: SSMS is a tool/interface to access your database engine... the version of SSMS is **not necessarily** the same as the version of your database engine which SSMS is connected to. Try `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: It's not about SSMS, it's about SQL Server version. `STRING_SPLIT()` is starting with 2016, and `TRIM()` function starting with 2017, so you need SQL Server 2017 to use both. It doesn't matter which SSMS you use.

Comment: That thought had crossed my mind. Doing SELECT @@VERSION gives: 

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4057116) - 11.0.7462.6 (X64) 
 Jan  5 2018 22:11:56

Comment: Ugh. I had a newer version but uninstalled because of a conflict with Studio Express. Let me try that again.

Answer (score 3):

TRIM was introduced in SQL Server 2017.  STRING_SPLIT in SQL Server 2016.  Are you connected to a database on an earlier version of SQL Server?

Comment: Instead of Inbuilt functions , if you are using Sql Server version which is below 2016, You could create user defined functions for Trim and Split String.

for Trim  - https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/09/sql-server-2008-trim-function-user-defined-function/

for Split String- https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-function-in-SQL-Server-Example-Function-to-Split-Comma-separated-Delimited-string-in-SQL-Server-2005-2008-and-2012.aspx

i hope this will help you .:)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT TRIM(VALUE) FROM STRING_SPLIT('a| b |c| d ','|')

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ERP_FN_TRIM
(@Stringa VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @StringaPulita VARCHAR(MAX),
                 @FlagSpazio    BIT;
         SET @StringaPulita='';
         SET @Stringa=LTRIM(RTRIM(@Stringa));
         SET @FlagSpazio=0;
         WHILE @Stringa <> ''
         BEGIN
             IF @FlagSpazio = 0
                 SET @StringaPulita=@StringaPulita + LEFT(@Stringa, 1);
             IF SUBSTRING(@Stringa, 2, 2) = '  '
             BEGIN
                 SET @FlagSpazio=1;
             END;
                 ELSE
             BEGIN
                 SET @FlagSpazio=0;
             END;
             SET @Stringa=SUBSTRING(@Stringa, 2, LEN(@Stringa));
         END;
         RETURN ISNULL(@StringaPulita, '');
     END;
```

Comment: Nice function, but I don't think it answers the question.